# Count specific months encountred between two days

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, google-workspace

im looking to count for specific months lets say month 6 and 7 because its holiday .

I have found this function on the [net here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/8bCq16TlISY)  in very down of page .

```
    =COUNT(FILTER(A2:A;(A2:A-DAY(A2:A))<=DATE(C1;D1;0);(B2:B-DAY(B2:B))>=DATE(C1;D1;0)))
```

where  C1 is year to search and D1 is the month number to search
and i have modified it like that

```
    =IF(YEAR(H204)=YEAR(J204);
COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAG(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(H204);6;0);(J204-DAY(J204))>=DATE(YEAR(J204);6;0)))+COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAG(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(H204);7;0);(J204-DAY(J204))>=DATE(YEAR(J204);7;0))) ; 
      IF(J204="";
         COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAY(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(H204);6;0);(J204-DAY(TODAY()))>=DATE(YEAR(H204);6;0)))+COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAG(H204))<=DATUM(YEAR(H204);7;0);(J204-DAG(TODAY()))>=DATE(YEAR(H204);7;0)))+
         COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAY(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());6;0);(J204-DAG(TODAY()))>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());6;0)))+COUNT(FILTER(J204;(H204-DAY(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());7;0);(J204-DAY(TODAY()))>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());7;0))); 
         COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAG(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(H204);6;0);(J204-DAY(J204))>=DATE(YEAR(H204);6;0)))+COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAG(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(H204);7;0);(J204-DAY(J204))>=DATE(YEAR(H204);7;0)))+
         COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAY(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(J204);6;0);(J204-DAY(J204))>=DATE(YEAR(J204);6;0)))+COUNT(FILTER(H204;(H204-DAY(H204))<=DATE(YEAR(J204);7;0);(J204-DAY(J204))>=DATE(YEAR(J204);7;0)))
         )
          )
```

because the first formulas is not really right .  From this function i wrote it works BUT  only when the second column `J204=""` is empty i want to use `TODAY`s date .

so i replaced this

```
  (J204-DAY(J204))    ---> (J204-DAY(TODAY())  in line4 and 5
```

But i dont know how to replace J204 ?

How can i make this working pls ?

**EDIT**

to make it clear i have just problem if the column J is empty (No date) so i want instead use `TODAY` instead of J204  so how can i switch this

```
   (J204-DAY(J204))  to   TODAY ??
```

Comment: you're mixing different programs / languages, which makes it really difficult to help. Please note that only Excel / english is on topic here (either raw translation is better then german(??) function names).

Comment: What language is your office running in? You have Year which is Englisch, Datum which might be German but Dag and Antal don't tell me anything. Day and Count maybe? Could be Belgian or Dutch?

Comment: @MátéJuhász  AND seth  hahaha im very sorry didnt notice the language , i have changed the language im very sorry

Comment: Please describe exactly what do you need, instead of just referring to something similar and posting your attempt. Questions should be self-explaining and be understandable on their own.

Comment: @MátéJuhász i have explained in my edit , i dont know how you didnt understand it .Just want to replace column 2 when its empty to to handle with TODAY .

Answer (score 0):

J204 is a cell reference. Either put `=TODAY()` into that cell or change every reference to J204 in that formula to another cell reference or `TODAY()`.

But from the question you're asking and what's being discussed in/on that link I'm not sure your formula does actually what you want to do? It sounds like you'd want the Output "June, July" while the formula attempts to get a count for the months that passed between two dates.

Comment: yes i want count june and july between first date and second date , and if second date is empty then i want use counting to today

Comment: you mean like that  `(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())`

Comment: Yes, at least that would correct for your last line in your question.